# Unable to connect Python Websocket server using Dart Client

Tags: python, flutter, dart, sockets

## Issue :

When I am trying to connect to server.py using client.py then it is working and I am getting the response like this [image]

But, when I am trying to connect to Python server using Dart then getting following error:
[image]

### My server.py file content:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('192.168.0.102', 59000))
server.listen()
client, address = server.accept()
client.send('You are connected'.encode('utf-8'))
```

### My client.py file content

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('192.168.0.102', 59000))
message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(message)
```

### My dart client

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://192.168.0.102:59000'),
  );
  channel.stream.listen(
    (data) {
      print(data);
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print('Error : $error');
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('192.168.0.102', 59000))
server.listen()
client, address = server.accept()
client.send('You are connected'.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is **not** implementation of WebSocket server, as it is not compliant with [`RFC 6455`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.html). If you want to use with WebSocket client, either alter your code that it is compliant with **all** normative parts of `RFC 6455` xor use ready WebSocket server implementation provided by external package for example [`websocket-server`](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-server/) but before using please comprehend its' [documentation](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server).